# How is the process called when getting persistent objects out of the persistent store?

Tags: iphone, core-data

"fetching ... " ... fetching what? Persistent objects? What's the scientific term when I send a request to an persistent store to get back an managed object?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are *fetching* managed objects and their faults.