# Is it fine to say that core data "deserializes" objects when fetching them from an persistent store?

Tags: iphone, core-data

Is it fine to say that core data "deserializes" objects when fetching them from an persistent store?

Comment: Didn't you just ask this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2078222/how-is-the-process-called-when-getting-persistent-objects-out-of-the-persistent-s ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. They are fetched or realized. Serialization is quite different.